# Adding a cloned git repo to my local repo

Tags: git, github

I cloned a github repo into my repo (let's say `https://github.com/foo/bar.git` ) to my local git hepo.
After doing `git add -A`, I see that git only created `my_repo/bar/` directory, but didn't add its content ... when I do a push to my github repo, the `bar` directory is empty. How can I add the content of the `bar` repo into my repo?
PS: I'm not trying to steal someone's code, it's because the entire project has to go together and `bar` is a dependence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git won't track files of another repository inside yours. There are two solutions:

- Clone the repository and delete the `.git` directory of the clone repository.
  The cloned repository will be part of your code, not a local repository anymore.
  You will not push or pull anything to the other repository.
- Go with Git [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). I think it is a better way:

`git submodule add https://github.com/foo/bar.git bar_local_dir`

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the source code and copy it to the local git repo .  Once you have done this , then push the code with your changes to your github repo.

This is what i interfere from your description.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do (but a submodule is probably a better way) is the following:

- Clean up the recipient, to minimize clashes (i.e., rename files out of the way, ...)
- Create a new branch for the repository to be integrated, and fetch it's master into it.
- Merge the new branch into the recipient's master branch

Better experiment on copies, doing this can screw up things badly...

(I did something similar when I squashed notes for two courses into one set of notes. Took me something like a full day until I was convinced nothing had gone missing. Not recommended for everyday use...)